# How to increase cakephp Auth component session expire time

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using Auth component to check user is logged in.

Here is my AppController's initialize function

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Md5',//My own password hasher
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Dashboard',
            'action' => 'login'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Its working fine.But if I stay inactive for few minutes(like 3-5min) and go(click) to a link it sends me login page.It seems session time expired.

How or Where I can increase this time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Auth component shares Session class

**For Cakephp3**

At config/app.php we can set the timeout.

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',        
    'timeout'=>24*60//in minutes
],
```

**For Cakephp2**

in your Config/core.php

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'timeout' => 31556926 //increase time in seconds
));
```

Comment: Hi, does it possible to increase the session time in app controller or any other controller.Because i what to change session time dynamically in admin panel.using cake php3

Comment: @RaghulRajendran Yes you can. Check this link https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

Answer (score 1):

Auth component shares Session class. For CakePHP 3 you can set session timeout at `config/app.php` like below:

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout'  => 1440, /*24 hours*/
    ],
```

Comment: Why to use block comment /* */ instead of using line comment // or #  ;)