# How to increase the login time for cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

Can you please let me know how to increase the session expiry time for CakePHP 2?

Currently, i set the configuration as bellow.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
                'timeout' => 129600, // The session will timeout after 30 minutes of inactivity
                'cookieTimeout' => 129600, // The session cookie will live for at most 24 hours, this does not effect session timeouts
                'ini' => array(
                   'session.gc_maxlifetime' => 129600 // 36 hours
                 )
    ));
```

But, these settings not work and session expired in almost 24 minutes.Thanks
This thread didn't solve my problem "[How to increase cakephp Auth component session expire time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694932/how-to-increase-cakephp-auth-component-session-expire-time)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase cakephp Auth component session expire time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694932/how-to-increase-cakephp-auth-component-session-expire-time)

Comment: I tried the solution mention in above question. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this configuration in core.php file of your application

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
'defaults' => 'cache',//default session
'timeout'  => '<time_in_minute>',//in minutes
'cookieTimeout' => '<time_in_minute>',//in minutes
'ini' => array('session.cookie_domain' => env('HTTP_BASE')),
'handler' => array(
    'config' => '<handler>' //if you are using default sessions then this field is not necessary
 )
));
```

Add time according to your requirement

Comment: Not working, this code even didn't allow me to login.